# Can Jira Issue validate fields within a sub-task

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

My current situation is I have a custom workflow which include many statuses.

For each Jira issue, has some sub-tasks.

I want a validation mechanism, which can prevent the Issue going to the next statuses until some certain custom fields have been validated. But the custom fields are not belong to Jira issue, they are belong to sub-tasks.

e.g.

```
 1. There are statuses: A, B, C, D, etc. for the workflow;

   2. There is an issue X who has Y and Z as sub-task; 

   3. Sub-task Y has a and b as custom fields;

   4. Sub-task Z has c and d as custom fields;

   5. The issue X won't go from status A to status B until custom fields a, b, c and d are validated.
```

Anyone knows are there any good plugins or method I can do like this.

NB: I know there is a plugin called Jira Suite plugin which is powerful, I can do some validation on transition, but the fields validation are only for issues, not include sub-task custom fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible to do this using the Jira scripting suite.
for information about fields and function usage,  have a look at the [issue API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/5.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html). To be more specific, you might want to use the function:  <kbd>Collection getSubTaskObjects()</kbd>

Next go trough the child-objects and check what ever fields you might need.

If you're having truble writing the code feel free to ask..